# Storing the history of 1 or many columns in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a request to store the date on which a specific field was changed in a table. For example, In my dbo.User table, we need to know when the IsActive flag was changed. With history.

I am proposing this:

1. New schema - History.
2. New table - [History].User_History

```sql
    CREATE TABLE [History].User_History (
      Id INT NOT NUL IDENTITY(1,1), <-- PK
      UserId INT NOT NULL, <-- FK to User.Id
      CaptureDate DATETIME DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE()),
      PrivacyId INT NULL
    )
```

PrivacyId (Or any column added) would be NULL, as we may add new columns, and existing rows would need to be left NULL, as we didn't know the value then)

All our Updates and Inserts are via Stored Procs (Yes, I know ...)

So those two procs will need to check if the new value of PrivacyId will change. If so, write a new row to the _History table.

We do not have the option to use CDC. So seems we have to find a more manual way to achieve this. Is my proposed solution suitable? Or are there barriers or better ways to achieve this?

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to skin this cat... for example you can store the changes as XML/JSON to avoid needing the schema of your history table to match the actual table. You can even use generic history tables where 2 columns are TableName & TableId. It really depends what you are going to use it for and how much work you want to put in. Personally I would do it in a trigger rather than the SP. Not only do you automatically have the before/after values available, but you can't sneak around it with a manual update which bypasses the SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine, as you are doing these using stored procedures. Also, your history table looks very simple. Maybe you can add, what kind of operation(INSERT, UPDATE) and who made the change.

```
CaptureDate DATETIME DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE()),
OperationType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PerformedByUser VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
```

As you told CDC is out of scope, you can think of out of the box options like,
[Temporal tables](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5211/sql-server-temporal-tables-vs-change-data-capture-vs-change-tracking--part-1/)